# iPhone frequently disconnects from 4G Network in Japan

Tags: iphone

I moved from Germany to Japan recently and have bought a physical SIM card from IIJmio. They use the NTT Docomo network. I still have my German eSIM active in the phone.

One problem I have here in Japan are frequent disconnects from the 4G network. This is especially noticeable while streaming videos, which requires a continuous connection. The disconnects look like this: the 4G indicator in the top right corner of the phone vanishes and shows no signal strength for a few seconds. After 10-15 seconds the 4G symbol appears again and connectivity is back. Sometimes this is also accompanied by 2 popups, which inform me that the default SIM for phone calls was changed. I assume the first one is for changing from Japan SIM -> German SIM and the second is switching back.

My phone is the iPhone 11 Pro. According to this site from Apple the model sold in Germany and Japan is the same. I would assume that this means the problem is not related to LTE bands.

To me this either looks like the connection from phone -> SIM is somehow faulty or something like a lease is expiring and the phone fails to extend the lease and ends up renegotiating everything with the cell tower.

Has somebody any idea how I could debug this behavior further? Or any clues on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this behaviour occur when you turn off the German eSIM?

Comment: It's not just the iPhone; the Google Pixel 7 also experiences the same issue.